# Geometry of one object changes (doesn't update) when I render the image

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects

I have a problem, I'm finishing a project and suddenly I have a strange problem.
Geometry in viewport looks like that:
[image]

And in viewport preview render like that:
[image]

But as I hit render, it changes a geometry of one of the objects to what it was many many hours ago before I edited it (Those brick-like things are longer):
[image]

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Do your bricks have any modifiers on them that have display in viewport disabled but still have the 'Use modifier with render' enabled? Same for just extra objects in your outliner. You may have objects that don't display in viewport but are set to render. Have you tried using Alt-H to make sure it's not hidden in viewport?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind... I must have duplicated an object in a few hours ago and it was invisible in viewport, but visible in render. I deleted it and it's ok now.